# Match the last element in a delimited list?

Tags: regex, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have some data that is separated by colons, like this:

```
foo:bar:baz:qux
```

I want to use regex to match the *last* element, in this case, `qux`. The list may be of any length, and if it is one element long, there will be no colons at all.

I've tried using vim's zero-width matching constructs, but I can't seem to get it to do what I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `$` anchor, which means the regex must match to the end of line.

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/
```

Comment: ...smart. I realized I kept trying to match what *wasn't* after (using `\@!` when I could've just used this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
:\?[^:]\+$
```

This is optional colon followed by one or more non-colon characters followed by the end of the line.